# Media Query не работают, когда их много

Tags: media-queries, css

Ставлю 1 media query - работает. Но когда их много - не работают!

Код такой:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 1024px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) and (max-height: 768px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) and (max-height: 1050px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) and (max-height: 900px) {...}
```

Во время проверки их - они работают. Но когда например после 5-го возвращаюсь к первому, второму - не работают. Как будто вообще стиль не задан.

Кто знает, с чего так может быть?

**UPDATE**

Использую IE8 и css3-mediaqueries.js

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить порядок описания -- от конца к началу:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) and (max-height: 900px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) and (max-height: 1050px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) and (max-height: 768px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 1024px) {...}
```

Comment: проблема такая: Допустим я написал 4-5 правил с одинаковой шириной, но разными высотами 1280х720, 1280х768, 1280х800, 1280х900 и допустим для каждого даны высоты 50, 100, 150, 200 соответственно. Тогда для первого вместо 50, отображает 200. Путается как бы. При том в условии я пишу и ширину и высоту. Вот в чем проблема?

Comment: никто не подскажет?